# Iterate through list of dictionories and compare with other dictionories

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I have the following dictionaries

```
dic1 = { 'T1': "HI , china" , 'T2': "HI , finland" ,'T3': "HI , germany"}

dic2 = { 'T1': ['INC1','INC2','INC3'] , 'T2': ['INC2','INC4','INC5'],'T3': ['INC2','INC5']}

dic3 = { 'INC1': {'location':'china'} , 'INC2': {'location':'germany'},'INC3': {'location':'germany'},'INC4': {'location':'finland'}}
```

I need to remove the values in dic2 based on the dic1,dic3

example :

1. I have to iterate through dic2 first and check the T1 and its INC values.
2. If the corresponding T1 key value in the Dic1 matches with the corresponding INC values in the dic3 the keep the value in dic2 otherwise pop the value.

Detaileded explanation given in the picture. And I am expecting the following output.

```
dic2 = { 'T1': ['INC1'] , 'T2': ['INC4'],'T3': ['INC2']}
```

[image]

example code :

```
for k, v in dic2.items():
for k1, v1 in dic1.items():
    if k is k1:
        print k
        for k2 in v:
            for k3 in dic3.items():
```

I am new to python. I have tried the above pieces of code and I got struck down.Could you please help me out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Can be done in a one-liner:

```
>>> {k: [i for i in v if dic3.get(i, {}).get('location', '#') in dic1[k]] for k, v in dic2.items()}
{'T1': ['INC1'], 'T2': ['INC4'], 'T3': ['INC2']}
```

`[i for i in v if dic3.get(i, {}).get('location', '#')` is the list comprehension to pick only the values from `dic2`'s lists if `dic3[i]['location']` is inside `dic1[k]`, where `i` is the key in dict `d3` and `k` is the key from dict `d2` as well as dict `d1`.

I used `dic3.get(i, {}).get('location', '#')` (rather than `dic3[i]['location']`, you get `KeyError` for key `INC5` which is not in `dic3`) to avoid the issue of key `i` not being in `dic3` (would return an empty `dict` for my next `.get`) and in the second `.get`, again I use it to return the `location` key's corresponding value if it exists and check if that returned string lies inside the values of dict `d1`.

I return `#` (can be any string/char) if I know that the key `i` doesn’t exist in `dic3` (`i` not existing will essentially give `{}.get('location', '#')` which in turn will give `#`, this is sure to fail the membership in `d1`, hence it's Ok).

Toned down for-loop version:

```
>>> ans = {}
>>> for k, v in dic2.items():
...     temp = []
...     for i in v:
...             if i in dic3 and dic3[i]['location'] in dic1[k]:
...                     temp.append(i)
...     ans[k] = temp
... 
>>> ans
{'T1': ['INC1'], 'T2': ['INC4'], 'T3': ['INC2']}
```

Comment: Spot on. one-liner is prob. too `dense` and hard to read in this case.  Maybe another version of `for-loop` to show and compare.  Great Job.

Answer (score 1):

From my understanding, you are supposed to modify the original dic2 dictionary rather than creating a new one for your answer, this is what I got:

```
delete = []

for key, value in dic2.items():
    loc = dic1[key][5:]
    for inc in value:
        if inc not in dic3:
            delete.append(inc)
        else:
            if loc != dic3.get(inc)['location']:
                delete.append(inc)

    for item in delete:
        value.remove(item)
    delete = []

print(dic2)

>>> {'T1': ['INC1'], 'T2': ['INC4'], 'T3': ['INC2']}
```

The first for loop iterates through dic2 and sets the location required to the variable loc. The next one iterates through the lists (values) and adds them to a delete list.
At the end of each loop, it iterates through the delete list, removing each element from the value list, and then setting delete to an empty list.

I am also relatively new to python so I am sure there could be efficiency issues.

Comment: This worked too..but I can approve only one. Thanks a lot for your response

Answer (score 1):

This is essentially the same as the other answers but as a one-liner, it may be more readable (maybe not, since it's subjective).

```
{k: [el] for k, v in dic2.items() for el in v if (el in dic3.keys() and dic3[el]['location'] in dic1[k])}
```